# Determinig all leafs nodes in a tree

Tags: recursion, data-structures, binary-tree

Can you guys help me with this method?
I had it with a return before but it didnt work either

```
private String leafNodes(TreeNode root, String leafs){  
    if (root.isLeaf()) {
        leafs += Integer.toString(root.getData());
    } 
    else {
        if(root.getLeft() != null) {
            leafs += leafNodes(root.getLeft(), leafs);
        }
        if (root.getRight() != null) {
            leafs += leafNodes(root.getRight(), leafs);
        }
        return leafs;
    }
    return leafs;  
}
```

Comment: what language is this btw?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you pass `leafs` to the children and then add the result to the current string so the same leaf can appear several times in the returned string. You can fix it this way:

```
private String leafNodes(TreeNode root){
    String leaves = "";  
    if (root.isLeaf()) {
        leaves = Integer.toString(root.getData());
    } 
    else {
        if(root.getLeft() != null) {
            leaves += leafNodes(root.getLeft());
        }
        if (root.getRight() != null) {
            leaves += leafNodes(root.getRight());
        }
    }
    return leaves;
}
```

Comment: @sp2danny It is not always "". If `root.getLeft() != null` and `root.getRight() != null`, then the first assignment `leaves += leafNodes(root.getLeft())` makes it equal to the leaves of the left subtree, and then `leaves += leafNodes(root.getRight())` concatenates it with the leaves of the right subtree.